# Python : To check within same list containing both sub-string and the full string ad combine them into one?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a list of names as :

```
name_lst = ['Johnny Depp', 'Depp', 'Tom Cruise', 'Tom', 'Evans', 'Chris Evans']
```

I need to convert the above list into a list where the elements compare with each other and thus match the appropriate name(string) with the suitable one.

TO be more precise, the sub-string in the above case "Depp" matches with the full string "Johnny Depp" so ,instead of Depp and Johnny Depp both existing, we must have only Johnny Depp. Same goes for other string elements.

Therefore,

Either update the previous list:

```
name_lst = ['Johnny Depp', 'Tom Cruise', 'Chris Evans']
```

or

```
new_name_lst = ['Johnny Depp', 'Tom Cruise', 'Chris Evans']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_name_lst = [i for i in name_lst if ''.join(name_lst).count(i)==1]
```

Here, we avoid items in the list which repeat more than once in the string made of the items of the list.
This gives:

```
['Johnny Depp', 'Tom Cruise', 'Chris Evans']
```